# Unity: How to disable gravity after instantiating and give it gravity back in XR

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I am making a VR game using the XR toolkit. I want to instantiate a gameobject and I want it NOT to move and just float in the air. After I grab it, it should have back the gravity/rigidbody etc. After I instantiate it i use the following code: `gameobject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;`
When I pick it up and drop it I set the gravity on true which does the job. The problem is, when I don't grab the object but hover with my hand over it or touch it, it starts flying and floating through the area. How can I make stop that? I'd be grateful if someone can help me out!

Kind regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code stop moving below.

```
rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
```

I hope it will work on your project.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
No, it didn't do the job :D It ended up spawning elsewhere
Another idea?